# Remove a single tab on a new Finder Window (Yosemite)

Tags: finder

I'm wondering if anyone else has had this problem? It's kind annoying, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

THE PROBLEM IS whenever I open a new finder window, it also creates a single tab that I can't close. This tab takes up some screen space and is kind annoying. I can't figure out how to make it go away. I've looked in View Options and Finder Preferences.

Here is a picture:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>  will show/hide the tab bar (if there is not more than one tab already).

It appears that if you close a Finder window with the Tab bar open, then subsequent window will start with it open, even for a single tab.

So I guess the trick is to always close tabbed windows one tab at a time, or remember the above key-combo for when you forget.

Comment: Me neither... ;)